# Let $ABC$ be a triangle and let $AM$ be a median. a) Express $AM$ in terms of $a,b,c.$ and Parallelogram Law

Tags: geometry

**Problem**

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and let $AM$ be a median.
a) Express $AM$ in terms of $a,b,c.$
b) Prove that the sum of the squares of the side lengths of a parallelogram equals the sum of the squares of the diagonals.

**What I Have**

a) We plug in $m = n = \frac{a}{2}$ into Stewart's Theorem:
$$b^2\cdot \frac{a}{2} + c^2 \cdot \frac{a}{2} = a\left( d^2 + \frac{a}{2} \cdot \frac{a}{2} \right).$$Divide both sides by $a$ and solve for $d:$
\begin{align*}
\frac{b^2}{2} + \frac{c^2}{2} &= d^2 + \frac{a^2}{4} \\
d^2 &= \frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{4} \\
d &= \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}}{2}}
\end{align*}

b) I am completely lost on this one, however. Can I get some help?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other, and half the diagonal is a median in some triangle.

Comment: @dxiv Are you suggesting that I use what I have from the first part to get the diagonal, which is 2* the median?

Comment: Yes, precisely.$\,\,$

Comment: Following up on my comment, in order to answer the implied question of why/how **a)** $\implies$ **b)**, consider a parallelogram $\,ABCD\,$ with the diagonals intersecting at $\,M\,$. Then $\,AM\,$ is a median in $\,\triangle ABC\,$, and using step **a)** it follows that:
 
$$
\begin{align}
AM^2 = \frac{2 AB^2+2AC^2-BC^2}{4} \;\;&\iff\;\; (2 AM)^2 + BC^2 = 2 AB^2 + 2 AC^2 \\
 &\iff\;\; AD^2 + BC^2 = AB^2+BC^2+CD^2+DA^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already nailed it but the easiest proof uses vectors and I'll present it here just for fun. I'll prove (b) and after that I'll solve (a):

[image]

$$\vec{d}=\vec{a}+\vec{b},\quad \vec{c}=\vec{b}-\vec{a}$$

$$d^2=\vec{d}\cdot\vec{d}=(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot(\vec{a}+\vec{b})=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}+2\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}+\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}$$

$$d^2=a^2+b^2+2\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}\tag{1}$$

Using the same approach you can easily prove that:

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}\tag{2}$$

Add (1) and (2) and your statement (b) is proved:

$$c^2+d^2=2a^2+2b^2$$

Back to (a). Look at the shaded triangle. The median $m$ that you want to calculate is half of diagonal $d$.

$$m=\frac d2=\frac{\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}}2$$

Done.